# plot.zoo - Plot one graph with different colors

Tags: r, time-series, finance, zoo, quantitative-finance

I want to plot a graph of a time series return on an asset with different colors for more volatile periods. I want the volatility clusters to be marked in red with the rest of the more calm periods marked in blue. I've attached an image of what I want to achieve.

My code:

```
plot.zoo(djr, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Returns", col = "blue")
```

[image: Daily return series (2 typical volatility clusters marked in red)]

Comment: For another way to represent this have a look at `?xblocks` in the zoo package.

Comment: Also there is a demo of overplotting in a different color here: `library(zoo); demo("zoo-overplot")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `cond` is a logical vector with your condition for more volatile periods (for example `cond <- abs(Returns > 0.05)`), you can use something like:

```
plot.zoo(djr, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Returns", col = "blue")
points(index(djr)[cond], djr[cond], type = "l", col = "red")
```

For multiple periods in red, lines may appear that go from one to the other. In the following example I solve this problem:

```
# Reproducible example:
library(zoo)
djr <- as.zoo(EuStockMarkets[, "DAX"])
djr <- (djr - mean(djr))/sd(djr)

cond <- abs(as.numeric(djr)) > 0.75
rlec <- rle(cond)

plot.zoo(djr, xlab = "Time", ylab = "Returns", col = "white")
ind <- 1
for(i in 1:length(rlec$values)) {
  points(index(djr)[ind:(ind + rlec$lengths[i] - 1)], 
         djr[ind:(ind + rlec$lengths[i] - 1)], 
         type = "l", col = c("blue", "red")[rlec$values[i] + 1])
  ind <- ind + rlec$lengths[i]
}
```

[image]

Comment: This works on DAX for me but not on other indices. I'm assuming it has something to do with the time scale. Do you mind annotating the steps for me?

Comment: Sure, first of all, you have to fix your condition for more volatile periods. With `rle` the changes in the condition (the color changes of the graph) are obtained. Then we paint the complete blank graphic, to finally add that piece of the corresponding color (`for`).

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Juan works. Here's an alternate method that I found works as well

```
ling_segs <-ifelse(djr <= -0.02 | djr >= 0.02, cbind(djr), NA)

line_segs <- na.omit(ling_segs)

plot.zoo(cbind(djr, line_segs),
     plot.type = "single", 
     xlab = "Date", ylab = "Returns",
     col = c("blue", "red"))
```